# Changes to VBA code to open a workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Whilst I was using Excel 2011 I had a VBA program that opened another workbook. However, having moved over to Excel 2016 it no longer works, even after changing the filepath format (obtained from another Stackflow posting). The current code reads:

[image: VBA program]

I am now getting the message `

> Microsoft Visual Basic Compile Error: Syntax error

Where am I going wrong? I have tried it with Workbook and Workbooks on the '`Dim`' line. The second VBA program at the bottom does open the file, so I know the path is correct

Comment: You are better off putting the code in your post - use the {} symbol for correct formatting.

Comment: File path should be in parentheses

Comment: Thanks this worked

Answer (score 0):

Use the following method instead

```
Set wb = GetObject("filepath\filename.xlsm")
```